# Парсинг одинаковых тегов в HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#

Моя проблема заключается в том, что у меня есть несколько тегов и они одинаковые. Мне необходимо сделать парсинг первого тега из этих нескольких одинаковых, но у меня парсится последний. Собственно вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы парсился первый тег?

Строки кода, которые я использовал для парсинга:

```
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            var web = new HtmlWeb()
            {
                AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };

            hd = web.Load("https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=" + slovo + "&langlist=1");
            foreach (HtmlNode item in hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr"))
            {
                textBox1.Text = item.InnerText;
            }
```

Comment: Что-то типа `var firstTrTag = hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr").First();` вместо цикла.

Comment: var tag =  hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr:first-child");

Comment: С "tr:first-child" помогло, спасибо

Comment: @ValeryLosev Тогда лучше `var tag = hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("tr:first-child");`

Comment: @ A K♦, согласен, забыл про обычный селектор

Comment: @ValeryLosev так может ответом?

Answer (score 0):

у тебя цикл foreach() - он работает для каждого элемента в множестве hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr"), то есть если в этом массиве 1й элемент = "a", 2й = "b", а 3й = "c", код присвоит textBox1.Text сначала "а", потом "b", потом "с", чтобы такого не было нужно создать множество всех нужных тебе элементов и брать только первый

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            var web = new HtmlWeb()
            {
                AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };

            hd = web.Load("https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=" + slovo + "&langlist=1");
List<string> list= new List<string>();
            foreach (HtmlNode item in hd.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr"))
            {
                list.Add(item.InnerText);
            }
textBox1.Text = list.ElementAt(0);
```